# Don't Print After decimal point in

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, c++, display

In my code, I have  `float Hz = 0.00;` I want to display values to my user in RPM as

```
Serial.print("Speed = ");
Serial.print(round(Hz*60);
Serial.println(" RPM);
```

The only hangup is that this displays as `Speed = XX.00 RPM` is there an easy way to get the Arduino to only print out `Speed = XX RPM`?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print):

```
Serial.print(round(Hz*60), 0);
```